# facebook graph api userpost fetching

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am using facebook graph api to fetch the user posts using php.I need to get the user posts from a start data. So i used the **since** parameter in the URL. this is my code for the above condition:

```
$url ="https://graph.facebook.com/FB_ID/feed?since=1%20june%202016&limit=25&access_token=ACCESS_TOCKEN";
$result = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
```

But this is returns an empty result. So i have tired with CURL.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/FB_ID/feed?since=1%20june%202016&limit=25&access_token=ACCESS_TOCKEN";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But both this attempts are getting empty/error messages. If we tried the URL without the **since** parameter, it's working fine.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/FB_ID/feed?limit=25&access_token=ACCESS_TOCKEN";
$result = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
```

If anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to format it as a time_range object.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FB_ID/feed?time_range={'since':YYYY-MM-DD,'until':YYYY-MM-DD}&limit=25&access_token=ACCESS_TOCKEN
```

OR

Try with since and until (Both)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FB_ID/feed?since=2011-07-01&until=2012-08-08&limit=25&access_token=ACCESS_TOCKEN
```

Comment: I have tried the url in browser directly by changing the since and until parameter values. but its fetching all the results. Not for the given condition